# Lock on "suspend", but do not lock on "suspend to swap" (hibernation)

Tags: hibernate, lock-screen, luks, cryptsetup

I enabled "lock on suspend" (sleep). This works fine, however this will also trigger when I hibernate the laptop. When I resume from hibernation, I have to enter two passwords: On the cryptsetup screen to unlock the drive and on the login screen.

Is there a way to not lock on hibernate (systemctl hibernate), but still lock on sleep?

---

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 (but I am flexible and will switch to any version, if that solves this problem).

Answer (score 1):

You could put together a script that you would use when hibernating, such that it first sets

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

and then hibernates.
Then use another script that runs after resume (you do not need here to be selective about executing *only* upon resume from hibernation, as it could run upon resume from suspend as well, in which case it will have no effect), which sets

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
```

I am not certain about the exact locations where to check/place for these scripts.
This idea is analogous to [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414088&p=13842468#post13842468) script `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/toggle-lock`, which might be very close to what you need

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "hibernate" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        pre)
            XINPUTUSER=$(who | grep :0 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/')
            DISPLAY=:0.0 su - $XINPUTUSER -c "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false"
            ;;
        post)
            XINPUTUSER=$(who | grep :0 | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).*/\1/')
            DISPLAY=:0.0 su - $XINPUTUSER -c "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true"
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

**Notes**:

1. [This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414088) asks about a similar issue, but with a much more specific target sequence of actions. Options there *might* be useful for you.
2. The link above uses `pm`, while Ubuntu 20.04 uses `systemd`. I am not certain they are "incompatible".
3. Overall, I could look for the details to come up with a tentative step-by-step list of instructions. I often do that, but I also personally consider it is appropriate for an answer to promote a solution method, and **the interested OP** to take the method and fill in the gaps with further tinkering.

**Related**

1. [Correct way to execute a script on resume from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313479/correct-way-to-execute-a-script-on-resume-from-suspend)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423524/script-that-is-executed-after-resuming-from-hibernation
3. https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/run-scripts-and-commands-on-suspend-and-resume-on-linux/